# How to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, android

i can't load images on gridview, it always crashes. log cat message "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException length=16 ; index=16" 
here is my code :

```
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.pic_1, R.drawable.pic_2,
        R.drawable.pic_3, R.drawable.pic_4,
        R.drawable.pic_5, R.drawable.pic_6,
        R.drawable.pic_7, R.drawable.pic_8,
        R.drawable.pic_9, R.drawable.pic_10,
        R.drawable.pic_11, R.drawable.pic_12,
        R.drawable.pic_13, R.drawable.pic_14,
        R.drawable.pic_15, R.drawable.pic_16,
        R.drawable.pic_17, R.drawable.pic_18,
        R.drawable.pic_19, R.drawable.pic_20,
        ........ R.drawable.pic_96 
        };
```

code :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 

    int width = metrics.widthPixels / 6;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels / 6;

    ImageView i;     
        i = new ImageView(mContext);
        i.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(height, height));
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);                         
    }

    if(mImageSet == IMAGE_SET_ONE) {           
        Integer[] images1 = new Integer[16];         
        System.arraycopy(mThumbIds, 0, images1, 0, 16);    
        i.setImageResource(images1[position]);
    } else if(mImageSet == IMAGE_SET_THREE) {

    ...........    
 }

    return i;       
}
```

Please help me..

Comment: what is the calling code? I presume it is failing on getItem(int position)

Comment: array indices start with zero. So, a 16-element array goes from 0 - 15.

Comment: Can you not just use try/catch to catch the exception? and deal with it then?

Comment: @blackbelt i've post the getView? what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

One thing I would suggest is, make sure `position` is less than `mThubIds` array length in following method. Array index starts from ZERO, if position is greater (or) equal to `mThumbIds` length, you will get `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException`.

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}
```

Example:

```
 @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        if(position < mThumbIds.length){
        return mThumbIds[position];
        }
      return null;
    }
```

Comment: Compile error, no return from getItem.

Comment: @PeteBelford: Correct, fixed. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if(position >= mThumbIds.length) return null;
    return mThumbIds[position];
}
```

Please shoot yourself for using hungarian notation.

Comment: How is he using Hungarian notation? Wouldn't that become `iwImgView` or `vMyImageView` ? :)

Comment: mThumbIds, m for member.  No matter, it is terrible.

Comment: I thought that `m`-ing was a C++ tell. Then again I think it's really a cheap student's way of not having to use `this.`

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer[] images1 = new Integer[16];         
System.arraycopy(mThumbIds, 0, images1, 0, 16);    
i.setImageResource(images1[position]);
```

you copy the first 16 `Integer`, from `mThumbIds` inside `images1`, but since `mThumbIds` containse more than 16 elements your `position` can be assume a value between 0 and `mThumbIds.lenght - 1` . When position is 16 you get your `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException`.  `You should use i.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);`

Comment: if i use i.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]); it will not take all elements on mThumbIds?

Comment: It will take the element at index position. What is your purpose?

Comment: i want to load 16 images/elements from mThumbIds for gridView. so i copy 16 first from mThumbIds to array images1 and setImagesResources from images1.

Comment: then let getCount return 16, and use mThumbIds. There is no need to copy it